# Functions in plpgsql are using consderable CPU

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm working with plpgsql functions, which are called sequentially, for example:

```
create function a() returns void
language plpgsql as
$$
declare
  v_ret integer;
begin 
  v_ret := (SELECT * FROM b());
end;
$$;


create function b() returns integer
language plpgsql as
$$
declare
  v_ret integer;
begin 
  v_ret := (SELECT * FROM c());

  return v_ret;
end;
$$;

create function c() returns integer
language plpgsql as
$$
declare
  v_ret integer;
  pointer record;
  v_ret_sum integer;
begin 

  for record in (select * from temp_table) LOOP
    v_ret := (SELECT * FROM d());

    v_ret_sum := v_ret_sum + v_ret;
  end loop;

  return v_ret_sum;
end;
$$;
```

They are running in parallel with sidekiq, being called from my ROR API.
My trouble is that my db CPU is going very high in this process. I'm using 5 threads, so 5 times the same function, but with different arguments, runs at the same time.

What's a better options? Just accept this high CPU ratio, or call `a` function, then `b` function, and then `c` function from my API?
Thanks!

Comment: I would say if all they are doing is accumulating a value (function `c()`) you don't need this many functions. Just a simple select would do. And of course function `d()` is not on the picture but having C with a loop (assuming temp_table is a big one) and for every row call a function D is bound to generate high processing requirements. This looks like a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to be honest.

Comment: Using `v_ret := b();` instead of `v_ret := (SELECT * FROM b());` is more efficient. Inside a loop this should make a difference

Comment: You need a better description.  None of your functions have any arguments, and the top level one doesn't return anything at all. So how are they being called with different arguments, and what is the point of doing any of this?

Comment: Functions an and b are obsolete and function c could be done without a loop. Looks like a bunch of functions without a design or a plan. Go back to the drawing board, make a new design and make it as simple as possible